# How to escap "..."

Tags: r, regex

I R imports columns with no colname as ...1 I need to replace this ... with something else

Trying:

```
str_replace("hi_...","/././.","&")
```

Comment: what is the expected output.  Do you need `"[.]{3}", "&")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to replace each dot `.` with `&`. You need to escape `.` as `\\.` and use `str_replace_all`. Try this,

```
library(stringr)  
str_replace_all("hi_...","\\.","&")
```

Output,

```
[1] "hi_&&&"
```

Just in case you want to replace all three dots with `&` (which I barely think you wanted), use this,

```
str_replace("hi_...","\\.\\.\\.","&")
```

OR

```
str_replace("hi_...","\\.+","&")
```

Another way to achieve same can be using `gsub`

```
gsub("\\.", "&", "hi_...")
```

Comment: do you have the regex for numbers?

Comment: Sure, for numbers you can use `\d+` and in R you need to escape slash so `\\d+`

Comment: can I match only if the word starts with a patter like "_NA"?

Comment: Sure, for matching a word that starts with `_NA` you can write it is `_NA\w*` Can you give more sample data and tell what you would expect out of it?

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
str_replace("hi_...", "[.]{3}", "&")
```